# How to wrap PHPExcel generated cells with a link

Tags: php, phpexcel

The cv column holds filenames of files uploaded to server.
How to wrap the cell values with a link to pull the files from server.

This is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT name,email,phone,cv from applicants";        
$res = $this->db->query($sql);
$exceldata="";
foreach ($res->result_array() as $row){
    $exceldata[] = $row;
}

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($exceldata, null, 'A3');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER)
```

I want the cell to show the value with link pointing to the file.
Desired output of the cells:

ex.  `href="http://examle.com/uploads/cv/ '. cell_value .'">cellvalue`

Answer (score 1):

Set the cell as a hyperlink, as described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#change-a-cell-into-a-clickable-url) and shown in the examples like [05featuredemo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php)

```
$cellValue = 123;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('E26')
    ->setValue($cellValue);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('http://examle.com/uploads/cv/' . $cellValue)
    ->setTooltip('Click here to access file');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [feature demo](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) in the PHPExcel package, there is an example of how to add a link to a cell.

Here's some mockup code for this:

```
$yourcell = "A3";

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($yourcell, 'www.example.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($yourcell)->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://www.example.net');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($yourcell)->getHyperlink()->setTooltip('Navigate to website');
```